# gcc assembly. Discussion about the value in cfa, %ebp, %esp and the number in directive, like 4 in .cfi_def_register 4, 4

Tags: c, assembly, callstack, gnu-assembler, dwarf

Question 1: when the line 8 is going to be performed, I infer both %esp and %ebp are equal to CFA - 4, and they point to the return address stored in stack. Is it right?

```
    :                 :
    |    whatever     | <--- CFA: the value of the stack pointer at the 
    :                 :      call site in the previous frame
    +-----------------+
    | line 43 address | <--- %ebp == CFA - 4?
    +-----------------+
```

The assembly:

```
  1         .file   "test_.c"
  2         .text
  3         .globl  fn1
  4         .type   fn1, @function
  5 fn1:
  6 .LFB0:
  7         .cfi_startproc
  8         pushl   %ebp
  9         .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
 10         .cfi_offset 5, -8
 11         movl    %esp, %ebp
 12         .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
 13         subl    $16, %esp
 14         movl    $1, -8(%ebp)
 15         movl    $2, -4(%ebp)
 16         movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
 17         movl    -8(%ebp), %edx
 18         addl    %edx, %eax
 19         leave
 20         .cfi_restore 5
 21         .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
 22         ret
 23         .cfi_endproc
 24 .LFE0:
 25         .size   fn1, .-fn1
 26         .section        .rodata
 27 .LC0:
 28         .string "count1 = %d\n"
 29         .text
 30         .globl  main
 31         .type   main, @function
 32 main:
 33 .LFB1:
 34         .cfi_startproc
 35         pushl   %ebp
 36         .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
 37         .cfi_offset 5, -8
 38         movl    %esp, %ebp
 39         .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
 40         andl    $-16, %esp
 41         subl    $32, %esp
 42         call    fn1
 43         movl    %eax, 28(%esp)
 44         movl    $.LC0, %eax
 45         movl    28(%esp), %edx
 46         movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
 47         movl    %eax, (%esp)
 48         call    printf
 49         movl    $0, (%esp)
 50         call    exit
 51         .cfi_endproc
 52 .LFE1:
 53         .size   main, .-main
 54         .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"
 55         .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

C codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int fn1()
{
    int a, b;

   a = 1;
   b = 2;

   return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    int count;

    count = fn1();
    printf("count1 = %d\n", count);

    exit(0);
}
```

Question 2: I don't know why **.cfi_offset 5, -8** should be inserted in the codes, and so do **.cfi_def_cfa_register 5**, **.cfi_restore 5** and **.cfi_def_cfa 4, 4**. I found how to use these directives:

- .cfi_offset register,offset
- Previous value of register is saved at offset, offset from CFA.
- .cfi_def_cfa_register register
- .cfi_def_cfa_register modifes a rule for computing CFA. From now on register will be used instead of the old one. Offset remains the same.
- .cfi_restore register
- .cfi_restore says that the rule for register is now the same as it was at the beginning of the function, after all initial instruction added by .cfi_startprocwere executed.
- .cfi_def_cfa register,offset
- .cfi_def_cfa defines a rule for computing CFA as: take address from register and add offset to it.

  So I'd like to know 1#, 2#, 3#... those number represent which register respectively.

Comment: For Q1: On entry, CFA holds the return address, and %esp = CFA - 4. However, %ebp != %esp (lines 40 - 42 adjust %esp). After line 8, %ebp = %esp = CFA - 8.